# Connect Vertica DB from node and Typescript application

Tags: javascript, vertica

I'm writing d3 visualization code to append counts and rectangle boxes around the counts on .JPEG image. In order to get dynamic data I used typescript+node JS+D3 JS. I need to use Vertica DB.

How to install plugin to connect to db from typescript+nodeJS?

I tried node-vertica plugin and could not integrate it properly.

Comment: Working with the below code, It's a simcode written in app.js file and run it with 'node app.js'(exactly followed the steps in the link https://codeforgeek.com/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/) but installed vertica addon instead of mysql(npm install vertica)

Looking into it to modify app.js into node web application to include d3js code and try to run it in localhost, while doing this I have been facing below issues:
npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

Answer (score 0):

```
---------------
Code in app.js:
---------------
var config = {
ssl: 'optional',
interruptible: true,
host: '*******',
user: '*********',
password: '********',
database: '********'
};

try {
conn = Vertica.connect(config, (err, conn) => {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
} else {
conn.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
conn.query("select * from *****", function (err, result, fields) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);
});
});
}
});
}
catch (error) {
console.log("Error has been caught --"+error);
}
```